# How to evenly space checkbox with rest of the text box and check box?

Tags: html, css

I want this checkbox to go under the text boxes aligned.

I have tried this below code CSS code and it helped with aligning text boxes but not the checkboxes

```
   label {
    width:135px;
    clear:left;
    text-align:right;
    padding-right:10px;
   }

   input, label {
    float:left;
   }


   <label><input type="checkbox" name="Yes" data-field- 
   type="Boolean">&nbsp;Will Attend</label>



<label for="Email Address">Email Address* </label><input type="text" name="Email Address" data-field-type="Text" required="required" data-validation-message="Required field.">

<label for="First Name">First Name</label> <input type="text" name="First Name" data-field-type="Text">

<label for="Last Name">Last Name</label>  <input type="text" name="Last Name" data-field-type="Text">
```

I expect checkbox to be aligned with Textboxes.

[image]

Comment: Please post the other part of the code which includes Email Address, First Name etc.

Comment: I dont know your textbox align with something

Answer (score 1):

Your `input[type=checkbox]` is inside the `<label>` take it out like the rest of the inputs and it works, as shown.

Although, for an option like yes/no, a radio button would be more suitable.

```css
label {
  width: 135px;
  clear: left;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

input,
label {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<label for="Email Address">Email Address* </label>
<input type="text" name="Email Address" data-field-type="Text" required="required" data-validation-message="Required field.">
<label>Will Attend</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="Yes" data-field-type="Boolean">
<label>Won't Attend</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="No" data-field-type="Boolean">
<label for="First Name">First Name</label> 
<input type="text" name="First Name" data-field-type="Text">
<label for="Last Name">Last Name</label> 
<input type="text" name="Last Name" data-field-type="Text">
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean all label right? Just add blank `&nbsp;` `<label>` and `clear: none;`

```css
label {
  width: 135px;
  clear: left;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

input,
label {
  float: left;
}

.Checkbox{
  clear:none;
}
```

```html
<label for="Email Address">Email Address* </label><input type="text" name="Email Address" data-field-type="Text" required="required" data-validation-message="Required field.">

<label for="First Name">First Name</label> <input type="text" name="First Name" data-field-type="Text">

<label for="Last Name">Last Name</label> <input type="text" name="Last Name" data-field-type="Text">
<label>&nbsp;<!-- Just Blank--></label>
<label class="Checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="Yes" data-field- 
   type="Boolean">&nbsp;Will Attend</label>
```

Comment: Thank you so much.. Is there way I can align the Text?  Email Address, First Name, Last Name far left aligned?. BTW boxes are aligned now.

Comment: Resize label's `width: ___px;` and maybe you need resize **width** in `.Checkbox` too

Comment: And if you need dynamic width you need to add `<div>` container to contain size of input

Comment: I tried width for the label, but all the label moves either left or right but I can't get that to align.

Comment: No, I mean First Letter of First Name, F and Last Name, L starts right under E ( Email Address).   E, F, and L are aligned. Currently, they are not.

Comment: Ok. Change `text-align: right;` and can you add `padding-left:` to stay far from left  like [here](https://jsfiddle.net/limitbrk/1qg57w0x/6/)